# can someone point the error in the merge function

Tags: java

On running the code It is showing `IndexOutBoundException`
and I don't know why it is happening.it is something to do with the merge function.

```
 public class MergeSort {

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<T> lst) {
        System.out.println(lst.size());

        mergeSort(lst, 0, lst.size() - 1);

    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergeSort(List<T> l, int low,int high) {

        if (low < high) {
            int mid = low +( (high-low) / 2);
            mergeSort(l, low, mid);
            mergeSort(l, mid + 1, high);
            merge(l, low, high, mid);

        }
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void merge(List<T> lst, int low,int high, int mid) {
        List<T> temp = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
            System.out.println(lst.get(i));
            temp.add(i,lst.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println();

        int i = low;
        int j = mid + 1;
        int k = low;
        while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
            if ((temp.get(i)).compareTo(temp.get(j)) <= 0) {
                lst.set(k, temp.get(i));
                i++;
            } else {
                lst.set(k, temp.get(j));
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        while (i <= mid || j <= high) {
            if (i <= mid) {
                lst.set(k, temp.get(i));
                k++;
                i++;
            } else if (j <= high) {
                lst.set(k, temp.get(j));
                k++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        for(T e:lst ){
            System.out.print(e+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:643)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:455)
    MergeSort.merge(MergeSort.java:34)
    MergeSort.mergeSort(MergeSort.java:22)
    MergeSort.mergeSort(MergeSort.java:21)
    MergeSort.mergeSort(MergeSort.java:20)
    MergeSort.sort(MergeSort.java:11)
    Main.main(Main.java:65)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception is being thrown on the line

```java
temp.add(i,lst.get(i));
```

That is because you are trying to set a value of a list in an index that does not exist. The variable `temp` points to an empty list; therefore any assignment to an index higher than 0 will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is documented in the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) interface:

> `void add(int index, E element)`
>
> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
>
> [...]
>
> Throws:
>
> [...]
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index > size())`

A straightforward solution to your problem, while not the most efficient, is to just initialize your temp list with null values right after creating it, then `set` instead of `add` the relevant values.

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void merge(List<T> lst, int low,
    int high, int mid) {

    List<T> temp = new ArrayList<T>();

    // Fill temp list with empty values
    for(int i=0; i<lst.size(); i++){
        temp.add(null);
    }

    // Set the values we are going to work on.
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        System.out.println(lst.get(i));
        temp.set(i,lst.get(i));
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IndexOutOfBoundsException means quite simply that you are attempting to access an element that does not exist.  Try checking whether the thing exists before you get it.

The error is telling you that you are trying to access the element at index 3 even though the list size is zero.